# Converting an equirectangular depth map into 3d point cloud

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d

I have a 2D equirectangular depth map that is a 1024 x 512 array of floats, each ranging between 0 to 1. Here example (truncated to grayscale):

[image: img]

I want to convert it to a set of 3D points but I am having trouble finding the right formula to do so - it's sort of close - pseudocode here (using a vec3() library):

```
for(var y = 0; y < array_height; ++y) {

    var lat = (y / array_height) * 180.0 - 90.0;

    var rho = Math.cos(lat * Math.PI / 180.0);

    for(var x = 0; x < array_width; ++x) {

        var lng = (x / array_width) * 360.0 - 180.0;

        var pos = new vec3();
        pos.x = (r * Math.cos(lng * Math.PI / 180.0));
        pos.y = (Math.sin(lat * Math.PI / 180.0));
        pos.z = (r * Math.sin(lng * Math.PI / 180.0));
        pos.norm();

        var depth = parseFloat(depth[(y * array_width) + x] / 255);

        pos.multiply(depth);

        // at this point I can plot pos as an X, Y, Z point
    }
}
```

What I end up with isn't quite right and I can't tell why not.  I am certain the data is correct.  Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Molly.

Comment: how about sharing the map so we can see what you dealing with and can also test ... for example you can convert it to grayscale image (yes it will loss precision but for testing its OK)... you can also preseve precision more if you use RGBA as 24 or 32 bit integer insetad fo just 8bit grayscale ... or use original file and post on drop box or ulozto.net or whenewer (but if such storage requires registration most of us will pass it)....

Comment: Good idea - I uploaded a sample depth image here https://i.imgur.com/jqvqoyG.png

Comment: I added it to your question .... is it 360x180 deg or 180x90 deg view? Have tried it in C++ for fun and it looks like its 180x90 deg view. added answer with mine code + previews

Answer (score 4):

Well looks like the texture is half-sphere in spherical coordinates:

- `x` axis is longitude angle `a <0,180> [deg]`
- `y` axis is latitude angle `b <-45,+45> [deg]`
- intensity is radius `r <0,1> [-]`

So for each pixel simply:

1. **linearly convert `x,y` to `a,b`**

   in degrees:

   ```
   a =         x*180 / (width -1)
   b = -45 + ( y* 90 / (height-1) )
   ```

   or in radians:

   ```
   a =                    x*M_PI / (width -1)
   b = -0.25*M_PI + ( 0.5*y*M_PI / (height-1) )
   ```
2. **apply spherical to cartesian conversion**

   ```
   x=r*cos(a)*cos(b);
   y=r*sin(a)*cos(b);
   z=r*       sin(b);
   ```

   Looks like you have **wrongly coded this conversion** as latitude angle should be in all `x,y,z` not just `y` !!! Also you should **not normalize** the resulting position that would corrupt the shape !!!
3. **store point into point cloud.**

When I put all together in VCL/C++ (sorry do not code in javascript):

```cpp
List<double> pnt;                   // 3D point list x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,...
void compute()
    {
    int x,y,xs,ys;      // texture positiona and size
    double a,b,r,da,db; // spherical positiona and angle steps
    double xx,yy,zz;    // 3D point
    DWORD *p;           // texture pixel access
    // load and prepare BMP texture
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->LoadFromFile("map.bmp");
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    xs=bmp->Width;
    ys=bmp->Height;
/*
    // 360x180 deg
    da=2.0*M_PI/double(xs-1);
    db=1.0*M_PI/double(ys-1);
    b=-0.5*M_PI;
*/
    // 180x90 deg
    da=1.0*M_PI/double(xs-1);
    db=0.5*M_PI/double(ys-1);
    b=-0.25*M_PI;

    // proces all its pixels
    pnt.num=0;
    for (                                 y=0; y<ys; y++,b+=db)
     for (p=(DWORD*)bmp->ScanLine[y],a=0.0,x=0; x<xs; x++,a+=da)
        {
        // pixel access
        r=DWORD(p[x]&255);  // obtain intensity from texture <0..255>
        r/=255.0;           // normalize to <0..1>
        // convert to 3D
        xx=r*cos(a)*cos(b);
        yy=r*sin(a)*cos(b);
        zz=r*       sin(b);
        // store to pointcloud
        pnt.add(xx);
        pnt.add(yy);
        pnt.add(zz);
        }
    // clean up
    delete bmp;
    }
```

Here preview for 180x90 deg:

[image: 180x90]

and preview for 360x180 deg:

[image: 360x180]

Not sure which one is correct (as I do not have any context to your map) but the first option looks more correct to me ...

In case its the second just use different numbers (doubled) for the interpolation in bullet **#1**

Also if you want to remove the background just ignore `r==1` pixels:

[image: no background]

simply by testing the intensity to max value (before normalization) in my case by adding this line:

```
if (r==255) continue;
```

after this one

```
r=DWORD(p[x]&255);
```

In your case (you have `<0..1>` already) you should test `r>=0.9999` or something like that instead.

Comment: Amazing - thank you @Spektre - I'm going to sit down with this and work my way through it. Really appreciate you taking the time to explain and write sample code.

Comment: In #1, why do you divide by (width-1) instead of just width? For my application I have a low res 8x8 depth camera covering 45 degrees FOV. It makes more sense to me that each pixel would represent 1/8th of the FOV than 1/7th.

Comment: @PeterGibson if you have 2 pixels covering FOV = 30deg then the difference between them is `30deg/(2-1)` ... (you apply the angle difference one time less because the starting point is already on its angle ...)

Comment: I guess it depends if you think of the pixels as a single point, or spanning an area? In a depth camera, the pixel collects light from an arc that spans the angle, whereas maybe in a lidar the pixel represents a measurement at a single point instead?

Comment: @PeterGibson all the Depth cameras I saw are using LASER so the depths are dots at single angle (usually at some fixed pattern and interpolated to image raster) not integration over area. But the -1 is from mathemathics/geometry  without it the resulting FOV would be bigger than it really is. Its the same like for Integer DDA line rasterizations without -1 you would end up with one pixel bigger line ...